# Що таке "рин"? Не можу знайти це слово

Tags: значення-слів

У поемі "Поет" Тодося Осьмачки:

> і стало чути тенькання краплин
>
> з цебра у воду - у криничний **рин**.

Не можу знайти це слово ані в СУМі, ані просто в Ґуґлі.

Answer (score 1):

Перед навединими вами рядками, є ще такі:

> криниця друга й разом **ринва** мокра
>
> держалася на двох безверхих кроквах.

Можливо, рин - це те саме, що і ринва (лише чоловічий рід). Автор міг просто упустити закінчення, щоб зберегти ритм вірша.

В СУМі є визначення слова "[ринва](http://sum.in.ua/s/rynva)":

> РИ́НВА, и, жін. Труба або жолоб для стікання води.

А ще (згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0) - дає посилання на словник Грінченка) це може бути "жолоб по якому спускають зайву воду". Згідно до сайту [Abby Lingvo Live](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0):

> Труба або жолоб для стікання води.

Comment: Тобто те, в що вода `рине` чи звідки ви`рин`ає ;-)
[Ось етимологія](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rinnen#German) до германського `rinne`.